# phpmyadmin asking for login after atualization

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

I updated phpMyAdmin to 4.8.0.1 but now it asks for **username** and **password** to login. I tried the following:

- Username: **root** | Password: **[null]**
- Username: **root** | Password: **(blank)**
- Username: **root** | Password: **password**

I've also tried changing this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

But this error keeps appearing on the login form:

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How can I solve this?

Comment: When MySQL gets installed it often assigns some kind of random default password. Check your MySQL logs for details.

Comment: @tadman where can i find that?

Comment: Wherever your `mysql.log` type file goes. It varies depending on your OS.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/recovering-mysql-root-password-xampp

Answer (score 0):

password "", should work; don't set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

move the config.inc.php file from the old installation to the main folder of the new installation.